# Run-everywhere statically-linked gcc binary for Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I have an old SuSE-10.1 setup which works basically fine, but has a broken YaST (package manager) and no gcc. (Yes, I am in progress of moving one website after another to another server to get rid of that fossil, so please don't tell me to "upgrade", but it's a slow process and I have to maintain it.)

To install anything from source, I need a C-compiler - preferrably one that doesn't need any shared libraries and runs on 32-bit.

Where can I get (or how can I create) such a binary?

Comment: download gcc rpm package and install it? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/novell-sles-suse-installing-software-packages-rpm-files/

Comment: I couldn't get an rpm for SuSE 10.1 (I found many links but all went to rpm-Archives which were removed)

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a precompiled version with [static-get](https://github.com/minos-org/minos-static)

```
static-get -x gcc
```